# For Loop keeps on executing even length is given in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I use a tibco API to get some service status(running or stopped). I need certain values from the json obtained. I used a for loop but that keeps on looping more than its length. Can some one please advise.

Below is the code

```
var async = require('async');
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

var API_PORT = "8079";
var ALL_DOMAIN_API = "/bw/v1/browse/domains?full=false&status=true";
var URLS = {
    cit1: "http://x.x.x.x",
    cit2: "http://y.y.y.y"
};

exports.getdomainstatus = function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body.env || !URLS[req.body.env]) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Enviroment details not found...!" });
        return;
    }

    var url = URLS[req.body.env] + ":" + API_PORT + ALL_DOMAIN_API;
    //console.log(req.body.env);
    //console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://a.a.0.0:50683')
    }).then(resRaw => {
        return resRaw.text();
    }).then(resJson => {
        if (!resJson || !resJson.length) {
            res.status(200).json({ domainstatus: [] });
            return;
        }

        resJson = JSON.parse(resJson);
        //console.log(resJson);

        var domainstatus = [];
        async.eachLimit(resJson, 1, (domain, callback) => {
            if (!domain || !domain.name) {
                callback();
                return;
            }

            var statusurl = URLS[req.body.env] + ":" + API_PORT + "/bw/v1/browse/apps?domain=" + domain.name + "&full=false&status=true";
            //console.log(statusurl);
            fetch(statusurl, {
                method: 'GET',
                agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://0.0.0.0:0000')
            }).then(resRaw => {
                return resRaw.text();
            }).then(itemJson => {
                if (!itemJson || !itemJson.length) {
                    callback();
                    return;
                }

                itemJson = JSON.parse(itemJson);

                if (!itemJson || !itemJson[0]) {
                    callback();
                    return;
                }
                // console.log("/////////////////////////////////////")
                // //console.log(itemJson)

                // console.log("===================")
                console.log(itemJson.length)
                //Here I get Output as 9

                console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")

                for (let i = 0; i < itemJson.length; i++) {
                    //itemJson = itemJson[0];
                    console.log(itemJson[i].name)
                    //Here I get correct output
                    var temp = {
                        owner: itemJson[i].owner,
                        name: itemJson[i].name,
                        date: itemJson[i].date,
                        description: itemJson[i].description,
                        status: itemJson[i].state,
                        domainName: itemJson[i].domainName,
                    }
                    console.log("--------")
                    console.log(i)
                    console.log(temp)
                    //domainstatus.push(temp);
                    //temp.status(200).json({ domainstatus: domainstatus });


                }

                callback();
            }).catch(err => {
                callback();
            });
        }, () => {
            console.log("All Completed...!")

        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });
}
```

I have tried foreach too, but in vain. Is this something to do with async.eachLimit . I have tried using second parameter of eachLimit as 1 instead of 10 but the same result. please find the below output.after 0 to 9 (itemJson.lenth) it again starts from 0 to 9 and repeats again.

```
BS_127_NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application
--------
0
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'BS_127_NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_PPE_001-CustomerOrderStatus.application
--------
1
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_PPE_001-CustomerOrderStatus.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_EX_003-CustomerOrder_EX.application
--------
2
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_EX_003-CustomerOrder_EX.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_FM_003_CustomerBillingAccount.application
--------
3
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_FM_003_CustomerBillingAccount.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_DW_008_UpsertCustomerOrder_DW.application
--------
4
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_DW_008_UpsertCustomerOrder_DW.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_DW_016-CustomerOrderStatus_DW.application
--------
5
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_DW_016-CustomerOrderStatus_DW.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Stopped',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_FM_004_01_NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application
--------
6
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_FM_004_01_NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_ANV_001-ResourceOrder_ANV.application
--------
7
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_ANV_001-ResourceOrder_ANV.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_FM_005-NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application
--------
8
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_FM_005-NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
9
BS_127_NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application
--------
0
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'BS_127_NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_PPE_001-CustomerOrderStatus.application
--------
1
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_PPE_001-CustomerOrderStatus.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_EX_003-CustomerOrder_EX.application
--------
2
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_EX_003-CustomerOrder_EX.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_FM_003_CustomerBillingAccount.application
--------
3
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_FM_003_CustomerBillingAccount.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_DW_008_UpsertCustomerOrder_DW.application
--------
4
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_DW_008_UpsertCustomerOrder_DW.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_DW_016-CustomerOrderStatus_DW.application
--------
5
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_DW_016-CustomerOrderStatus_DW.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Unreachable',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_FM_004_01_NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application
--------
6
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_FM_004_01_NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_ANV_001-ResourceOrder_ANV.application
--------
7
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_ANV_001-ResourceOrder_ANV.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
AS_FM_005-NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application
--------
8
{ owner: undefined,
  name: 'AS_FM_005-NotifyCustomerOrderStatus.application',
  date: undefined,
  description: '',
  status: 'Running',
  domainName: 'CustomerOrderManagementService' }
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
9
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not just running *this loop* inside *another loop* or otherwise just calling the functionality twice?

Answer (score 0):

You have double loop, async.eachLimit already loops over your json, and each such iteration, has also for in it, this is double loop, remove either the for inside and stay with the async.eachLimit or stay with the for without using async.eachLimit.
(better of course use async then looping with for synchronously)

Comment: Sorry if I m using wrong approach. I just removed the for loop alone in the same code and executed . I get the below output (just to test)  and it keeps going on. Based on what it is taking the number of counts for looping?                                                                                                       +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
9
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
9
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
9
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
9
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++